An integral in analytic number theory
Show that
$$2 \cos(2n\pi x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int \frac{\pi^{s-\frac{1}{2}} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}s\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}s\right)} (nx)^{s-1} \, ds$$
the integral being taken along a line $C$, parallel to the imaginary
axis, between $\sigma=1/2$ and $\sigma = 1$.
After computing the residue at $s=2k+1$, $k\in N\cup\{0\}$, I find that the sum of the residue just the left hand side. I take the contour a rectangle-- the right side is $C$, and the left side is a vertical strip at the negative infinity. The upper side is a line parallel to x-axis at the positive infinity. However, I can not show that the integration along the lower,upper and left side of our contour is zero. I think I need some bound results for gamma function. Can anyone give me some hint?

Edited: It is from ‘Summation formulae and their relation to Dirichlet’s series II’ by W. L. Ferrar.
I quote the related part below. I still expect a method of residue theorem.

the integral being taken along a line, parallel to the imaginary
axis, between $\sigma=1/2$ and $\sigma = 1$.
the integral being absolutely convergent. Accordingly,


$$
\int_\beta \frac{x^{s-\frac{1}{2}} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}s\right)}{2\pi i \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}s\right)} \varphi(s) n^{s-1} ds
$$


$$
= \int_\beta \frac{x^{s-\frac{1}{2}} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}s\right)}{2\pi i \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}s\right)} n^{s-1} ds \int_0^\infty f(x) x^{s-1} dx. \tag{7}
$$


In this repeated integral we can change the order of integration\textsuperscript{5)} and so, after a simple calculation of residues, write it as


$$
2 \int_0^\infty f(x) \cos 2n\pi x \, dx. \tag{8}
$$


$\beta > 0$ would be enough for (6) and (7), but $\beta > \frac{1}{2}$ is necessary for the change from (7) to (8).


are you sure your result is correct? where is it from?

For the function
$$f'(x)=2 \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos(2 \pi n x)\tag{1}$$
the term-wise Mellin transform
$$\mathcal{M}_x2 \cos(2 \pi n x)=\int\limits_0^{\infty} 2 \cos(2 \pi n x), x^{-s} , dx=2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right), \Gamma(1-s), n^{s-1}\tag{2}$$
is valid for $0<\Re(s)<1$ (assuming $n>0$), so your selection of $\frac{1}{2}<\alpha<1$ is overly restrictive.
The related series
$$\zeta(s)=2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right), \Gamma(1-s) \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{s-1}\tag{3}$$
converges for $\Re(s)<0$.

For the function
$$f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor-(x-\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{\pi} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2 \pi n x)}{n}\tag{4}$$
with first-order $f'(x)$ derivative defined in (1) above, the related term-wise Mellin transform is
$$s, \mathcal{M}_x\left\frac{\sin (2 n \pi x)}{\pi n}\right=s \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin (2 \pi  n x)}{\pi  n}, x^{-s-1} , dx=2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right), \Gamma(1-s), n^{s-1}\tag{5}.$$

@Conrad It is from ‘Summation formulae and their relation to
Dirichlet’s series II’ by W. L. Ferrar
